# How to avoid SOQL Queries Inside FOR loops

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I have a maps `Map<string, String> envelopeAndStatus` which actually holds some `envelopeId` as key and corresponding `status` as a value in the map.

What I would like to do is, update the corresponding status for an envelopId in a salesforce object.

My case can be depicted like below

[image]

So, I have to update the `Envelope_Status__c` field of `Docusign_History__c` object with the map `envelopeAndStatus`

My code snippet is

```
public void updateDocusignHistory()
{
    System.Debug('5');
    List<Docusign_History__c> dhs = [SELECT Id, Envelope_ID__c, Envelope_Status__c FROM  Docusign_History__c WHERE Envelope_ID__c IN :envelopeAndStatus.keySet()];
    if(dhs.size() > 0)
    {    
        for (String k : envelopeAndStatus.keySet()) 
        {                               
            // What to do here ??
            // NEED TO UPDATE THE Envelope_Status__c FIELD

        }
    }                    
}
```

But, I have to avoid the SOQL inside for loop as it will raise the `SOQL 101 issue`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet is good, but I would use a new list of Docusign_History__c in order to store only the ones that really need to be updated.
If the Envelope_Status__c are already correct, you could spare a DML.

```
public void updateDocusignHistory()
{
    System.Debug('5');
    List<Docusign_History__c> dhsToUpdate = new List<Docusign_History__c>();
    for (Docusign_History__c dh : [SELECT Id, Envelope_ID__c, Envelope_Status__c FROM Docusign_History__c WHERE Envelope_ID__c IN :envelopeAndStatus.keySet()])
    {
        if (dh.Envelope_Status__c != envelopeAndStatus.get(dh.Envelope_ID__c))
        {
            dh.Envelope_Status__c = envelopeAndStatus.get(dh.Envelope_ID__c);
            dhsToUpdate.add(dh);
        }
    }

    if (!dhsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update dhsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

This way the method `updateDocusignHistory` has only one SOQL and only one DML statement

That's what'll happen according to the data in your example:

1. the SOQL will return 4 records
2. the value of Envelope_Status__c will be update for every record except the one with id = 1.
   This one is already correct.
3. once the loop ends only one dml will be executed (and only if needed) for the records with id [2-4]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. This is what, I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct and update a record as long as you know its Id. **There is no need for any query**.

```
List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>();
for (String recordId : myMap.keySet())
{
    records.add(new MyObject__c(
        Id = recordId,
        OtherField__c=valueFromMap
    ));
}
update records;
```

Comment: What if the `id` is not the primary key for the object rather than another unique key? I have updated my question for better understanding. Please have a look.

Comment: If the field is marked External Id you can upsert on it.

Comment: I mean if `custom_field__c = recordId,` what will be the approach ?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to first select all envelopes, and then do the processing.

Here's an example code which basically reduces the number of SOQLs to 1. Here I first collect the whole list of envelope ids. Then select all the envelopes and their related document histories by the ids. And only after that I do the processing using the selected data.

```
Docusign_History__c dh = null;
Set<id> envelopIds = new Set<id>();
for(Integer i = 0; i<envelopeAndStatus.size(); i++ )
{
    envelopeIds.addAll(envelopeAndStatus[i].keySet());      
}

List<Envelope__c> envelopes = [SELECT Id, (SELECT id FROM Docusign_Histories__c) FROM Envelope__c WHERE Id IN :envelopeIds];

for (Envelope__c e : envelopes)
{
        List<Docusign_History__c> dhs = e.Docusign_Histories__c;
        if(dhs.size() > 0)
        {
            dh = dhs[0]; 
            dh.Envelope_Status__c = envelopeAndStatus[i].get(k);
            // update dh;
        }
    }              
}
```

Comment: `dhs` would never be null... specifically, the result of a query is never a null variable, always an empty list.

Comment: @sfdcfox that's true. I just copy pasted the code from the question, will edit it.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have updated my question, can you have a look.